# How do I automatically set WooCommerce Product to draft after 14 days of creation

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi I want to change published products to drafts automatically after 14 days of its creation
only simple and variable product type to go to drafts after 14 days can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

add_action('save_post_product', 'mp_sync_on_product_save', 10, 3);
function mp_sync_on_product_save( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  if ( $update ) {
    return;
  }

  $_14_days_later = strtotime( '+14 day' );

  wp_schedule_single_event( $_14_days_later, 'wp_cron_set_product_status_to_draft', array( $post_id ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_cron_set_product_status_to_draft', 'set_product_status_to_draft', 10, 1 );
function set_product_status_to_draft( $product_id = null ) {
  $product_id = intval( $product_id );

  if ( $product_id <= 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

  if ( $product === null || $product === false ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
    wp_update_post( array(
      'ID' => $product_id,
      'post_status' => 'draft'
    ) );
  }
}
```